# How to verify when an unknown object created by the code under test was called as expected (pytest) (unittest)

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have some code that creates instances from a list of classes that is passed to it. This cannot change as the list of classes passed to it has been designed to be dynamic and chosen at runtime through configuration files). Initialising those classes must be done by the code under test as it depends on factors only the code under test knows how to control (i.e. it will set specific initialisation args). I've tested the code quite extensively through running it and manually trawling through reams of output. Obviously I'm at the point where I need to add some proper unittests as I've proven my concept to myself. The following example demonstrates what I am trying to test:

I would like to test the `run` method of the `Foo` class defined below:

```
# foo.py
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self._stuff = stuff

    def run():
        for thing in self._stuff:
            stuff = stuff()
            stuff.run()
```

Where one (or more) files would contain the class definitions for *stuff to run*, for example:

```
# classes.py

class Abc:
    def run(self): 
        print("Abc.run()", self)

class Ced:
    def run(self): 
        print("Ced.run()", self)

class Def:
    def run(self): 
        print("Def.run()", self)
```

And finally, an example of how it would tie together:

```
>>> from foo import Foo
>>> from classes import Abc, Ced, Def
>>> f = Foo([Abc, Ced, Def])
>>> f.run()
Abc.run() <__main__.Abc object at 0x7f7469f9f9a0>
Ced.run() <__main__.Abc object at 0x7f7469f9f9a1>
Def.run() <__main__.Abc object at 0x7f7469f9f9a2>
```

Where the list of *stuff to run* defines the object classes (*NOT* instances), as the instances only have a short lifespan; they're created by Foo.run() and *die* when (or rather, sometime soon after) the function completes. However, I'm finding it very tricky to come up with a clear method to test this code.

I want to prove that the `run` method of each of the classes in the list of *stuff to run* was called. However, from the test, I do not have visibility on the `Abc` instance which the `run` method creates, therefore, how can it be verified? I can't patch the import as the code under test does not explicitly import the class (after all, it doesn't care what class it is). For example:

```
# test.py
from foo import Foo

class FakeStuff:
    def run(self):
        self.run_called = True

def test_foo_runs_all_stuff():
    under_test = Foo([FakeStuff])
    under_test.run()
    # How to verify that FakeStuff.run() was called?
    assert <SOMETHING>.run_called, "FakeStuff.run() was not called"
```

Comment: If your code under test is something like `Foo` above, then **you** have complete control about what you pass into it, and thus complete visibility on what happens when each `run()` method is called.

Comment: btw, I think you mean that the `Foo.run()` method executes: `stuff = thing(); stuff.run()`

Comment: Do you have ctrl over `Abc, Ced, Def` code? If you do - you can wrap the run method with a decorator.

Comment: I think the example of `FakeStuff` means that the test passes whatever it likes into `Foo()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you correctly realise that you can pass anything into `Foo()`, so you should be able to log something in `FakeStuff.run()`:

```py
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self._stuff = stuff

    def run(self):
        for thing in self._stuff:
            stuff = thing()
            stuff.run()

class FakeStuff:
    run_called = 0
    def run(self):
        FakeStuff.run_called += 1

def test_foo_runs_all_stuff():
    under_test = Foo([FakeStuff, FakeStuff])
    under_test.run()
    # How to verify that FakeStuff.run() was called?
    assert FakeStuff.run_called == 2, "FakeStuff.run() was not called"
```

Note that I have modified your original `Foo` to what I think you meant. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! - Stupidly (probably because it's late and I've been working a long time now) I completely forgot about the fact I can use class attributes.... DOH!!!

I was sort of thinking about going down the route of using patch and wandering how that could work - I'm fairly confident it can't.